# How to remove all layers and features from map?

Tags: jquery, leaflet, mapbox

I am working on a map and I would like to remove all features from the map on a certain event. The features are in multiple layers which are plotted dynamically.

Some of the code is:

```
$.getJSON('distributor-companies', function (data) {
                var layers = [];
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    if (item.geojson != '') {
                        layers[i] = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);
                        $.getJSON('/geojson/' + item.geojson, function (data) {
                            layers[i].setGeoJSON(data);
                            // Loop over the added layer
                            layers[i].eachLayer(function (layer) {
                                // Add click event
                                layer.on('click', function (e) {
                                    // Do stuff
                                    map.fitBounds(layers[i].getBounds());
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
```

Is there a way to fetch all layers on the map at a certain point in time and remove them.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Loop over all the layers added to the map using the `eachLayer` method of `L.Map`, then call the `removeLayer` method of `L.Map` on each of them:

```
map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    map.removeLayer(layer);
});
```

References:

`eachLayer`: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-eachlayer

`removeLayer`: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-removelayer

Please note that this wil remove ALL the layers from your map. That means also any tilelayers etc. I think in your case it would be best if you do not add all your featureLayers to the map instance, but create a group for them:

```
// Create group for your layers and add it to the map
var layerGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);

$.getJSON('distributor-companies', function (data) {

    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        if (item.geojson != '') {
            // Add the new featureLayer to the layerGroup
            var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(layerGroup);
            $.getJSON('/geojson/' + item.geojson, function (data) {
                featureLayer.setGeoJSON(data);
                featureLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
                    layer.on('click', function (e) {
                        map.fitBounds(featureLayer.getBounds());
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Now you can call the `clearLayers` method of `L.LayerGroup` which will clear of the current layers in the group:

```
layerGroup.clearLayers();
```

Reference:

`L.LayerGroup`: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup

`clearLayers`: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-clearlayers

Answer (score 11):

You can use the following truthy check to see if it's a valid geoJSON object:

```
map.eachLayer(function(layer) {
  if (!!layer.toGeoJSON) {
    map.removeLayer(layer);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the mabox-gl draw library, There is a function to do this.

```
draw.deleteAll().getAll();
```

This deletes all the features and layers on the map.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [iH8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28646383)'s answer but more concise if you want to **remove all layers apart from the tile layer**. Just check if the layer is a tile layer by i.e. checking the `_url`:

```
var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'

map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    if (osmUrl != layer._url){map.removeLayer(layer)};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using this. My layer type was "fill" and layer name was "source_tiles_1", "source_tiles_2", "source_tiles_3"

```
map.getStyle().layers.forEach((layer) => {
       if(layer.id.match(/source_tiles/g)){
          map.removeLayer(layer.id);
          map.removeSource(layer.id);
         }
     });
```