# Leaflet - remove all map layers before adding a new one

Tags: javascript, android, maps, leaflet, layer

as title says I have problems removing maps before adding a new one, I have this function, which draws the tile given by a Spinner (parameter values are strings with correct leaflet tile names):

```
function drawMap(tile){ 
    map.addLayer(tile);
    map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        if (layer !== tile) {
            map.removeLayer(layer);
        }
   });
}
```

Variable map is initialized this way, and it doesn't generate problems:

```
var map = L.map('map').fitBounds([
        [myPosJSON.NEBoundLat, myPosJSON.NEBoundLng],
        [myPosJSON.SWBoundLat, myPosJSON.SWBoundLng]
    ]);
```

How can I fix the drawMap() function to correctly display maps? (I also have to do it with a group of Overlays, but probably the procedure is the same for maps)

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28646383/199364).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking for name after adding your new layer, try removing all layers first and then add the new layer:

```
function drawMap(tile){ 
    map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        map.removeLayer(layer);
    });
    map.addLayer(tile);
}
```