# MapBox in cljs: Removing markers from map (after storing them in an atom)

Tags: clojurescript, mapbox-gl-js, clojurescript-javascript-interop

**Background:**

In `mapbox-gl-js`, while you can remove layers and features from a map (because the references are stored), [you cannot do the same with markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155523/mapbox-clear-all-current-markers). Instead one has to store the reference to any added marker, otherwise one won't be able to remove them later.

```
var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker().addTo(map);
marker.remove();
```

**Setup:**

I have an atom where I add every marker I create, so I can later clean them.

```
(defonce markers (r/atom []))

(defn add-marker [map img coordinate]
  (let [marker (create-marker img)]
      (.setLngLat marker (clj->js coordinate))
      (.addTo marker map)
      (swap! markers conj marker)))

(defn clear-markers []
  (doseq [m (array-seq markers)] (.remove m))
  (reset! markers []))
```

If I call `clear-markers` however, nothing happens. No error, no warning, the marker just stays in the map.

If I remove the marker right after adding (just to try it out), it works as described in the docs:

```
(defn test-marker [map img coordinate]
  (let [marker (create-marker img)]
      (.setLngLat marker (clj->js coordinate))
      (.addTo marker map)
      (.remove marker)))
```

Obviously, with this code, the marker will be removed right after adding and thus never be on the map, which is not the desired behaviour, just a test.

I also tried other approaches on how to call `.remove` on the elements of the vector, the following was my very first try:

```
(defn clear-markers []
  (map #(.remove %) markers))
```

I'm fairly new to Clojure(Script), so I try to understand where my mistake is.

- Is the object in my vector not the same instance maybe, so removing it, will not affect the marker on the map?
- Or do I have to do a different approach, when trying to execute sideeffected methods on objects in a vector?
- Or did I miss something else entirely?

Comment: I don't know how `r/atom` is different, but I assume you need still need to deref it (`@markers`) to iterate them.

Comment: I think deref is just to tell Reagent to re-render my component on state change. That being said, I tried it nonetheless and it yields the same results: none.

Comment: You were right, after all. I had to deref in order to access the _content_ of the atom. Otherwise I just accessed the atom object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a quick guess, try replacing `map` with `doseq` here:

```
(defn clear-markers []
  (doseq [marker @markers]
    (.remove marker)))
```

The `map` function is lazy and won't run until it has to.  Since it appears you are after a side-effect to remove markers, `doseq` is the right choice.  It is intended for side-effects and always runs immediately. It always returns `nil`.

Also, you need to deref `markers` to get a vector, then just use that in `doseq`.  Do not use `array-seq` since the atom stores a plain Clojure/Script vector, not a JS array.

Another tip:  always prefer `mapv` to `map`.  It is eager and removes many timing- & lazy-related issues. Be sure to study [the Clojure CheatSheet](https://clojure.org/api/cheatsheet) and [the CLJS version](https://cljs.info/cheatsheet/).

Also, beware that Reagent makes a big difference between a Clojure list vs a vector.  You sometimes need to force an (eager) vector result into a `seq` with `(seq ...)` or a list via `(apply list ...)`.  You can also use the simple [->list](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.200/api/tupelo.core#-%3Elist) function to emphasize what you are doing:

```
(s/defn ->list :- [s/Any]
  "Coerce any sequential argument into a List."
  [arg :- [s/Any]]
  (apply list arg))
```

Comment: I tried `(doseq #(.remove %) @markers)` but it won't compile: _doseq requires a vector for its binding_. I'm more and more convinced, I'm not storing a proper vector with `(defonce markers (r/atom []))`.

Comment: Sorry!  Typed the answer too fast.  Fixed now.

Comment: I can't believe, that did it. I was fighting with this little problem almost the whole day. And it was really just about accessing the atom properly in combination with the missing deref. Thanks!