# Adding a lot of georeferenced images makes mapbox very slow

Tags: mapbox, raster, mapbox-gl-js

I have a map for which I have to add a lot of (about 150) images on a map.

I've seen their example [Add a raster image to a map layer](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/image-on-a-map/), which shows that you need to **add a source** with coordinates, then **add a layer** to display your image on the map.

I made a loop to add all my images, but **it makes my map really laggy when moving on it**; see demo [here](https://tribunaldesprejuges.org/V2/).
I was working with Leaflet before, and it was handling that nicely.

**Is Mapbox supposed to work fine with a lot of images loaded, and is there strategies to make it render smoothly?**

One attempt that I made is that I was wondering if this was due to a excessive amount of layers; and searched how to add multiple images on a same layer (same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66210679/mapbox-gl-js-how-to-add-multiple-photo-sources-on-a-single-layer)); but haven't found a way to do it: this does not work:

```
        //add source
        map.addSource("imagesSource", {
            type: "geojson",
            data: {
              "type": "FeatureCollection",
              "features": [
                  [
                      {
                          "type": "image",
                          "url": "http://url/image1.png",
                          "coordinates": [
                              [
                                  4.3813338557822,
                                  50.842573058675
                              ],
                              [
                                  4.418685805334,
                                  50.842573058675
                              ],
                              [
                                  4.418685805334,
                                  50.825893099756
                              ],
                              [
                                  4.3813338557822,
                                  50.825893099756
                              ]
                          ]
                      },
                      {
                          "type": "image",
                          "url": "http://url/image2.png",
                          "coordinates": [
                              [
                                  4.3981741530879,
                                  50.835614531226
                              ],
                              [
                                  4.402177428321,
                                  50.835614531226
                              ],
                              [
                                  4.402177428321,
                                  50.833826839538
                              ],
                              [
                                  4.3981741530879,
                                  50.833826839538
                              ]
                          ]
                      },
                      {
                          "type": "image",
                          "url": "http://url/image3.png",
                          "coordinates": [
                              [
                                  4.3813338557822,
                                  50.842573058675
                              ],
                              [
                                  4.418685805334,
                                  50.842573058675
                              ],
                              [
                                  4.418685805334,
                                  50.825893099756
                              ],
                              [
                                  4.3813338557822,
                                  50.825893099756
                              ]
                          ]
                      }
                  ]
              ]
          }
        });

        //add layer
        map.addLayer({
          "id": 'imagesLayer',
          "source": 'imagesSource',
          "type": "raster",
          "paint": {"raster-opacity": 0.85}
        })
```

NB There is another example named [Add a georeferenced image](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/georeference-imagery/), which is confusing since this one is for adding a tileset; which is not my case: I want to be able to handle each image individually (toggle a selection, etc).