# How to remove all layers from the map?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I have a function which removes all my layers from the map individually:

```
function resetMap() {

map.removeLayer(Frog1Layer);
map.removeLayer(Frog2Layer);
map.removeLayer(Frog3Layer);
map.removeLayer(Frog4Layer);
map.removeLayer(Frog5Layer);
map.removeLayer(Frog6Layer);
map.removeLayer(Frog7Layer);
map.removeLayer(Frog8Layer);
}
```

I assume there's a better way? I tried making them into a group but the issue is, I have already added them to the map separately so they can be triggered by buttons on my page, and I don't know how to group them without adding them to the map as a group.

I tried the following:

```
function resetMap() {

    var allLayers = L.layerGroup([Frog1Layer, Frog2Layer, Frog3Layer, 
    Frog4Layer, Frog5Layer, Frog6Layer, Frog7Layer, Frog8Layer])

    map.removeLayer(allLayers);
}
```

and it doesn't work. The Web Console says "t is not defined" but I don't know what this means? What is t and why does L.layerGroup not work? How do I do this? Sorry, I'm new to Javascript.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28646317/how-to-remove-all-layers-and-features-from-map ? (The answer appears to be `map.eachLayer(function (layer) { map.removeLayer(layer); });`)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how to use this?? Can you elaborate

Comment: The code in my comment can be used as the entire content of your `resetMap` function, and when run, it will remove all layers from `map`.

Comment: It removed the map itself?? Is that supposed to happen? I want to keep the map tiles, but delete the 8 data layers.

Comment: Ah, okay, that clarifies things. Your question is not how to remove *all* layers but how to remove a specific set of layers as concisely as possible. I'll answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the layers you want to remove in an array, you can use `forEach` to iterate over the layers and remove each one from your `map`:

```
var layerArray = [Frog1Layer, Frog2Layer, Frog3Layer, Frog4Layer, Frog5Layer, Frog6Layer, Frog7Layer, Frog8Layer];
layerArray.forEach(function(layer) { map.removeLayer(layer); })
```

Removing a `LayerGroup` does not work unless that specific `LayerGroup` was added to the map. If you plan to use these layers together in other ways, it may be worth structuring them as a `LayerGroup`. If you want to do that, add them to the `LayerGroup` and then use `map.addLayer` to add the group object, instead of doing `map.addLayer` for each layer .

Comment: Thank you! Using an array seems like the right idea, but I am still getting an alert in the WebConsole that says "t is undefined"
Any idea what could be causing this?